# Using dom-repeat with jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, dom, polymer, jquery-bar-rating, dom-repeat

I am currently using this jQuery plugin for my Polymer project.

I am able to get the demo working, however I want to be able to dynamically generate rating fields for the **movie rating theme**.

My attempts at this was to create an array that contained the value I wished to give the bar ratings. The only thing that's throwing me off is that when I use dom-repeat to dynamically create my option tags, no options show up. However, when I don't use dom-repeat the options appear. I'm wondering if it has something to do with shadow dom (I've been reading up on it and still am not too familiar with its workings).

Doesn't work:

```html
<select id="example">
   <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{options}}" as="rating">
      <option value="[[option.title]]">[[option.title]]</option>
   </template>
</select>
```

Works:

```html
<select id="example">
    <option value="Bad">Bad</option>
    <option value="Ok">OK</option>
    <option value="Good">Good</option>
</select>

...

  ready: function () {
    var example = Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelector('#example');

    $(example).barrating({
      theme: 'bars-movie',
      showSelectedRating: false,
      deselectable: false,
      showValues: true
    });

  },
```

Comment: It should be `[[item.title]]` instead of `[[option.title]]`

Answer (score 0):

In your `dom-repeat` template, you set the iterator item name to `rating`, but you're binding to `option.title` inside the template (note the usage of `option` instead of `rating`). You probably meant to name the iterator `option` instead of `rating`.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{options}}" as="option">
```

[codepen](http://codepen.io/tony19/pen/ENomdM?editors=1010)